# Why this integral vanishes for $t\leq 0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, semigroups, cauchy-integral-formula

I am studying semigroup theory and in the proof of Hille-Yosida theorem, we have the integral
$$\int_{\omega'-i\infty}^{\omega'+i\infty} \frac{e^{\lambda t}}{\lambda^3}R(\lambda;A)A^3u \, d\lambda$$
Where $A$ is a linear operator, $R(\lambda;A)$ its resolvent operator  and $\omega'>\omega$ (we know that the spectre of $A$ is contained in the half space {$\Re(\lambda) \leq \omega$}).

My question is why this integral vanishes for $t\leq 0$ ?
I think we can use Cauchy's integral theorem but i don't know how.